# VoiceOver: UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, voiceover, uiaccessibility

Using VoiceOver, `UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: someView)` just re-announces the currently focused element instead of moving focus and announcing the accessibilityLabel of `someView`.  Even calling `UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: "what the heck")` does nothing and just re-announces the currently focused element, when it should announce the string passed in as the argument according to the docs.  I'm currently running Xcode 11.3.1 on the simulator.  Tried on a physical device as well and same problem.  Any help would be gladly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that this `post` function only actually focuses on the passed in view when running on a physical device, and seems to be broken on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the target element `someView` is not an Accessibility Element. Check if `someView.isAccessibilityElement` is set to `true`.